# Auto-posting Facebook posts to blog

Tags: blog

Is there a plugin or programmatic way to automatically to take a Facebook account's posts, and automatically post it to a wordpress blog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used this in the past: http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-facebook-feed/

You can see it in action here: http://www.iratex.com toward the bottom of the page on the left.